# Why is my Excel VBA code changing the references in the entire table instead of only the new row added?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that is supposed to add a new row to table "Ranking" in sheet "Dashboard" whenever a new sheet is added, and then link the first and second cells in that new row to specific cells in the new sheet. The creating a new row and linking to the correct cells works fine, but every time I add a new sheet, it also changes every other existing row in the table to the cells in the new sheet.

Say the table was:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

And when I add a new sheet it turns into:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 |

What I want it to be is:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |

Any idea why that is and if there is any way to fix this?

The code is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim RankingsTable As ListObject
    Dim NewRow As ListRow

    ' Reference the "Rankings" table in the "Dashboard" sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RankingsTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").ListObjects("Rankings")
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Check if the active sheet is not the "Dashboard" sheet
    If Sh.Name <> "Dashboard" Then
        ' Add a new row to the "Rankings" table if it exists
        If Not RankingsTable Is Nothing Then
            Set NewRow = RankingsTable.ListRows.Add
            ' Set the values in the new row based on the references you mentioned
            NewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Formula = "='" & Sh.Name & "'!R5C3"
            NewRow.Range.Cells(1, 2).Formula = "='" & Sh.Name & "'!R30C3"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not tested but normally tables created as listobjects got a default behaviour related to formulas applying the same formula to whole column. If you manually replicate your issue, you will see Excel pops up an icon to autocomplete column with same formula in whole column and because you are using VBA my guess is that this is happening without you noticing. Try not using a listobject but just a bunch of cells that visually look like a table but they are not really a table. Check [this](https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/prevent-table-formula-autofill/) to understand properly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists`

To keep track of the original setting it is stored in a private variable in the ThisWorkbook module

By calling `checkAutoFillFormulasInLists` before and after each list rows insert you will avoid the "error" you described.

```vb
Option explict
Private m_UserSettingAutoFillFormulasInLists As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    m_UserSettingAutoFillFormulasInLists = Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim RankingsTable As ListObject
    Dim NewRow As ListRow

    ' Reference the "Rankings" table in the "Dashboard" sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RankingsTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").ListObjects("Rankings")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
    ' Check if the active sheet is not the "Dashboard" sheet
    If Sh.Name <> "Dashboard" Then
        ' Add a new row to the "Rankings" table if it exists
        If Not RankingsTable Is Nothing Then
            checkAutoFillFormulasInLists False
                Set NewRow = RankingsTable.ListRows.Add
                ' Set the values in the new row based on the references you mentioned
                NewRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Formula = "='" & Sh.Name & "'!R5C3"
                NewRow.Range.Cells(1, 2).Formula = "='" & Sh.Name & "'!R30C3"
            checkAutoFillFormulasInLists True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub checkAutoFillFormulasInLists(fValue As Boolean)

If fValue = False And m_UserSettingAutoFillFormulasInLists = True Then
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
Else
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = m_UserSettingAutoFillFormulasInLists
End If

End Sub
```